Proof that a function is injective with special condition
Condition:
A is a finite set, $f:A \rightarrow A$,and we know that $f_i(a)=f(f_{i-1}(a))$ with $f_0(a)=a$.
Proof that if there exist a $i_0$ with $f_{i_0}(a)=f_0(a)$ then f is injective.
I have no idea what to do.
At first I thought that I could begin with $f(a)=f(b)$ and write that as $f(f_0(a))=f(f_{i_0}(a))$ but I think that's not useful.
Could someone give me a hint?

Since $f_{i_0-1}\circ f=f_{i_0}={\rm id}_A$ is injective, so is $f$.

@AnneBauval Thank you very much! Sorry that I asked such a question

Does the condition hold for all $a$?  And if so, does $i_0$ depend on $a$?

@JensSchwaiger Yes for all a and $i_0$ is independent.

@AnneBauval I'm not sure about your solution. Isn't $f\circle\f_{i_0-1}=f_{i_0}$ Could you maybe explain it to me? Thank you for your great help!

Which step are you unsure? The 1st equality or the "since...so..."?

Yes  that step. Isn't it $f(f_{i_0-1})=f_{i_0}$ In my country we would write this as $ f  \circ f_{i_0-1} =f_{i_0}$

$ f_i=f\circ f\circ\dots\circ f$ ($i$ times). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function

I understood it. Sorry I'm bad in math. Thank you very much for you time and help

If you are able to  know when you have understood and when you have not, you are not "bad in math".

It seems that $f$ is  injective even if $i_0$ may depend on $a $ and also for arbitrary, possibly infinite, sets $A$.

@JensSchwaiger That's very interesting. Maybe this problem is a special case of something more interesting

Injective means that for every $a \in A$ there is a $p_a\in A$ so that $f(p_a)=a$.  Let $p_a = f_{i_0-1}(a)$.  Then $f(p_a)= f(f_{i_0-1}(a))=f_{i_0}(a) = f_0(a)=a$.  So $f$ is injective.  This seems like a small part of a larger problem.  Refering to $i_0$ as $i_0$ rather than someithing simplier such as $i$ or $k$ is odd (what's the subscript $0$ supposed to mean).  And why the emphasis that $f_0(a)=a$ and why say $f_{i_0}(a)=f_0(a)$ rather than just $f_k(a) = a$?  And A being finite is never used.

@fleablood What you described as injectivity (and proved) is actually surjectivity.

Really?  Um.... geez.  That's embarrassing.  Maybe somewhere in the back of my mind I was thinking for finite sets injective if and only if surjective.  Still okay.  If $f(a) = f(b)$ then $f_{i_0-1}(f(a)) = f_{i_0-1}(f(f(b))$ and so $f_{i_0}(a) = f_{i_0}(b)$ and $a=b$ so injective.  Still doesn't use finiteness. Which I guess means such a function is bijective whether the set is finit or not. [Unless $i_0 < 1$.  But if $i_0 = 0$ then $f = identity$ so...]

Consider more generally, as suggested by @JensSchwaiger, for some (possibly infinite) set $A$, a function $f:A\to A$ such that for every $a\in A$, there exists an integer $n_a\ge1$ such that $f_{n_a}(a)=a$.
Note that by construction, $f_n=f^n:=f\circ f\circ\dots\circ f$ ($n$ times), the $n$-th iterate of $f$.
The relation $\sim$ on $A$ defined by
$$x\sim y\iff\exists k\ge0\quad y=f^k(x)$$
is obviously reflexive and transitive. Using the specific hypothesis on $f$, one easily shows that $\sim$ is also symmetric.
Now, if $c:=f(a)=f(b)$ then $a\sim c\sim b$, so that $a$ and $b$ belong to the "orbit of $c$", namely to $O:=\{c,f(c),f^2(c),\dots,f^{n_c-1}(c)\}$. The restriction $f_{|O}$ of $f$ to $O$ satisfies $(f_{|O})^{n_c}={\rm id}_O$. Therefore, $(f_{|O})^{n_c-1}\circ f_{|O}$ is injective, hence so is $f_{|O}$, whence the desired conclusion: $a=b$.
